# \@ifpackagelater equivalent for babel's lan­guage def­i­ni­tion files?

Tags: conditionals, babel, languages

It is possible to make conditional constructs based on the version `⟨date⟩` of a `⟨package⟩`, thanks to `\@ifpackagelater{⟨package⟩}{⟨date⟩}{⟨yes⟩}{⟨no⟩}`. So far, so good.

But this doesn't work for `babel-*` "packages" (in fact lan­guage def­i­ni­tion files):

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\makeatletter
\@ifpackagelater{english}{2012/08/20}{%
  \typeout{After}
}{%
  \typeout{Before}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

as the corresponding files are `.ldf` and not `.sty` files.

Is there another way for conditional constructs based on the version `⟨date⟩` of lan­guage def­i­ni­tion files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In LaTeX, Version dates can be declared by:

```
\ProvidesClass{<class name>}[YYYY/MM/DD ...]
\ProvidesPackage{<package name>}[YYYY/MM/DD ...]
\ProvidesFile{<file name>}[YYYY/MM/DD ...]
```

and LaTeX provides:

```
\@ifclasslater
\@ifpackagelater
```

`\@iffilelater` is missing and both commands can only be used in the preamble.

Package `ltxcmds` closes the gap by defining the complete set:

```
\ltx@ifclasslater
\ltx@ifpackagelater
\ltx@iffilelater
```

All three commands can also be used *after* `\begin{document}`.

Example:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{ltxcmds}
\makeatletter
\ltx@iffilelater{english.ldf}{2012/08/20}{%
  \typeout{After}
}{%
  \typeout{Before}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The babel language files use `\ProvidesFile` with some version information argument -- this setup is necessary to use the `LaTeX` core macro `\@ifl@ter` to check the file date, if it is applied with the correct extension.

It checks the file date, see the definition and the usage in `latex.ltx`:

```
\def\@ifl@ter#1#2{%
  \expandafter\@ifl@t@r
    \csname ver@#2.#1\endcsname}
\@onlypreamble\@ifl@ter
\def\@ifl@t@r#1#2{%
  \ifnum\expandafter\@parse@version#1//00\@nil<%
        \expandafter\@parse@version#2//00\@nil
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \fi}
\@onlypreamble\@ifl@t@r
\def\@parse@version#1/#2/#3#4#5\@nil{#1#2#3#4 }
\@onlypreamble\@parse@version
% Some lines omitted
\def\@ifpackagelater{\@ifl@ter\@pkgextension}
\def\@ifclasslater{\@ifl@ter\@clsextension}
\@onlypreamble\@ifpackagelater
\@onlypreamble\@ifclasslater
```

As can be seen, the macros `\@ifpackagelater` and `\@ifclasslater` do not have arguments actually (they are moving!) and the final treatment of the `{true}{false}` branches is left over to `\@ifl@t@r`.

So all that is to the is to define a separate macro that checks for a babel definition file, say `\@ifbabellater` and provide the `\@b@belextension` here.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@b@belextension{ldf}
\def\@ifbabellater{%
  \@ifl@ter\@b@belextension%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{babel}
\makeatletter
\@ifbabellater{english}{2012/08/20}{%
  \typeout{After}
}{%
  \typeout{Before}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

In my setup it prints 'After' on the console.

Apparently, there's a package for such macros, but I've done with core methods ;-)