# \ltx@iffilelater (now) returns false results for babel's lan­guage def­i­ni­tion files

Tags: conditionals, babel, languages

The present question follows [\@ifpackagelater equivalent for babel's lan­guage def­i­ni­tion files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/309680/18401) which was about conditional tests based on the version ⟨date⟩ of `babel`'s lan­guage def­i­ni­tion files.

The accepted answer of this related question suggested to use `\ltx@iffilelater`. But this command now returns false results, as pointed out by the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[english,french]{article}
\usepackage{ltxcmds}
\usepackage{babel}
%
\makeatletter
\ltx@iffilelater{english}{2016/03/20}{%
  \typeout{After (english)}
}{%
  \typeout{Before (english)}
}
\ltx@iffilelater{frenchb.ldf}{2016/03/20}{%
  \typeout{After (french)}
}{%
  \typeout{Before (french)}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

that prints on the console:

```
Before (english)
Before (french)
```

which are false results:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
   babel.sty    2017/09/18 3.13 The Babel package
 english.ldf    2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
  french.ldf    2017/09/07 v3.3c French support from the babel system
scalefnt.sty    
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
 ***********
```

BTW, the other answer provided in the related question returns incoherent results, as pointed out by the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[english,french]{article}
\usepackage{ltxcmds}
\usepackage{babel}

\makeatletter
\def\@b@belextension{ldf}
\def\@ifbabellater{%
  \@ifl@ter\@b@belextension%
}
%
\@ifbabellater{english}{2016/03/20}{%
  \typeout{After (english)}
}{%
  \typeout{Before (english)}
}
\@ifbabellater{frenchb}{2016/03/20}{%
  \typeout{After (french)}
}{%
  \typeout{Before (french)}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

that prints on the console:

```
After (english)
Before (french)
```

Comment: I get `Before (english)`, `After (french)` from your first MWE and I have the same dates in file list for {english,french}.ldf

Comment: After correcting your first mwe to use `english.ldf`,  not only `english` I get `After (english)` `After (french)`

Comment: for english your code is missing the .ldf ending, for french: the file is now french.ldf and not frenchb.ldf.

Comment: @jfbu As you get `After (french)`, maybe your TeX distribution isn't up to date? Sorry to both of you for `english` instead of `english.ldf`. Maybe should I remove the "english" part of my question and change its title to something more relevant, e.g. "\ltx@iffilelater (now) returns false results for *french* babel's lan­guage def­i­ni­tion file"

Comment: @UlrikeFischer indeed my babel is not yet updated, it is still at `2017/06/29 3.12`. I was too tired to compare the complete file list and this is why in my comment I said "for  {english,french}.ldf" which should have read  "{english,frenchb}.ldf". I guess after updating babel I will get same result as him.

Comment: Denis, I think you didn't really registered the differences between french.ldf and frenchb.ldf. Look at the `b` at the end. In a newer system you should now compare french.ldf as the name frenchb.ldf is obsolete.

Comment: @DenisBitouze it was normal I got `After (french)` even with my not completely up-to-date TL2017, because the test was checking if later than `2016/03/20` which was indeed the case. I have now updated, and testing `frenchb.ldf` indeed produces `Before (french)` which is counter-intuitive, the frenchb.ldf does exist as a stub file, `\ltx@iffilelater` does not know how to extract a date I guess. Testing with french.ldf I get `After (french)` as normal and expected.

Comment: @jfbu I know get (with `\ltx@iffilelater`) for both files `After`:  `After (frenchb) After (french)`, which is correct as they are both new on my system.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I get (with `ltx@iffilelater` too) `After (english)`, `After (french)`,  `Before (frenchb)`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I get `After (english)`, `After (french)`, `After (frenchb)` when passing `frenchb` rather than `french` as document class option (using `\ltx@iffilelater` on fully updated TL2017).

Comment: @jfbu. After an update I get now the same as you, before babel was still loading frenchb.ldf. (Obviously the test is always false if the file has not been loaded at all).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I did really registered the differences between `french.ldf` and `frenchb.ldf` :) The point of changing the question's title is to let other users who were tested the date of `french(b)` (okay, probably not many) to find more easily this discussion: such a question (and your comments) would have been helpful for me who have been bitten by the recent change in `babel` that, as you said, now doesn't load `frenchb.ldf`.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé it does load `frenchb` if you pass it the `frenchb` option. But you get the deprecation and removal warning (as has been the case for some time) (this gets on my nerves actually, because what can I do about my legacy documents; I am not going to massively replace `frenchb` by `french` therein)